# How can I implement this method's code better

Tags: ios, ipad, avfoundation

I'm making an app using AVFoundation that is essentially a photobooth with a view to play a video and a view to display and record video. Right now I'm implementing  all of the code in the
viewDidLoad of that view but I figure there's probably a better/faster way.

viewDidLoad of view that plays video

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_2311" ofType:@"mov"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    self.MoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    self.MoviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;

    [self.MoviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(192, 20, 640, 480)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.MoviePlayer.view];
    self.MoviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;
    [self.MoviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [self.MoviePlayer play];
}
```

And viewDidLoad of view that displays and records video

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.countdown setHidden:YES];

    self.df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.df setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [self.df setTimeStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    NSError *error = nil;
    self.session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    [self.session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium];
    [self.session setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480];

    self.videoInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:[self frontFacingCamera] error:&error];
    [self.session addInput:self.videoInputDevice];
    self.movieoutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    [self.session addOutput:self.movieoutput];

    AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    self.audioInputDevice = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:nil];
    if([self.session canAddInput:self.audioInputDevice])
        [self.session addInput:self.audioInputDevice];

    Float64 TotalSeconds = 300;
    int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;
    CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale);
    self.movieoutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
    self.movieoutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;
    CALayer *rootLayer = [[self view] layer];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:self.session];
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
    captureVideoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    [captureVideoPreviewLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(192, 20, 640, 480)];
    [rootLayer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];
    [self.session startRunning];
}
```

Comment: I think you'd be better of posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user3251122 - Hey check this link a quick overview how thinks work over here http://stackoverflow.com/tour